# How are joint measurements of quantum states realized experimentally?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation, epr-experiment

I have a question regarding the experimental implementation of joint measurements of quantum states.

While I understand for example the teleportation protocol using Bell states, something that still bothers me is the actual implementation. Specifically, what it means to measure two states simultaneously e.g. of the EPR-photon and the quantum state Alice's ion is in.

Could someone elaborate on this or give some useful reference?

Comment: @gIS: the OP is asking about the details of Alice's measurement—she measures the joint state of two particles.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about Alice's measurement. An example with superconducting qubits or ion traps would be nice.

Comment: You can make arbitrary joint measurements by first applying a quantum gate and then making measurements on single qubits. I'm pretty sure this is how it's done in ion traps.